# <form id="form1" runat="server">, Warnings

Tags: html, css, runatserver

I use this code to make my page have same height in a browser, it works, but when i check the code for mistakes, it gives me 3 warnings:

**Warning:**

```
<form> proprietary attribute "runat"
```

**Warning:**

```
<form> lacks"action" attribute
```

**Warning:**

```
<script> inserting "type" attribute
```

The code I use:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     </form>
     <script language="javascript">
          function autoResizeDiv()
         {
           document.getElementById('main').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
        }
        window.onresize = autoResizeDiv;
         autoResizeDiv();
    </script>
```

Should I ignore those warnings? and as a method is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

> `<form>` proprietary attribute "runat"

`runat` is ASP.NET. You should be checking the output of your ASP.NET, not the server side code.

If you aren't using ASP.NET, you shouldn't be using `runat`

> `<form>` lacks"action" attribute 
>   `<script>` inserting "type" attribute

HTML 5 makes these attributes optional.

Either you are not using HTML 5 (in which case you probably should be) or you are using an out of date QA tool. For HTML validity try [the W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: I do not use ASP.NET, and I edit my page in PsPad editor, so is better to use html5?

Comment: HTML 5 best represents how browsers actually handle HTML, so it is a sensible choice.

Comment: HTML5 is work in progress and contains a (good) description of actual browser behavior, proposed new features that have been implemented to a varying degree, and proposed features that have not been implemented at all. Without making a distinction. Yet, it is the best approach in practice to code by HTML5, but with caution.

Answer (score 0):

`runat="server"` is asp.net specific attribute. It wont work in generic html scenario. What tech you are using for front end
HTML4/5, PHP, ASP.NET

You should consider building your form tag soemthing like this (Taken from this page itself):

`<form id="search" action="" method="get" > </form>`

Comment: As i said above I do not use ASP.NET, I used your suggestion and it works,but stil gives me warnings.